# How to stop change ip powershell script from looping

Tags: powershell, automation

Hi all and thank you for all the help. I am still fairly new to powershell scripting so the answer might be simple but can't find it. I have the below script but after changing the ip of the first computer it loops and doesnt proceed to the next steps. Any ideas?

```
$ComputerName = Import-Csv "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1.txt" -Header name,IP
$MaskBits = 27 
$Gateway = "172.24.80.193"
$Dns = "172.25.193.32"
$IPType = "IPv4"
foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
# Retrieve the network adapter that you want to configure
$adapter = Get-NetAdapter -cimSession $Computer.name | ? {$_.Status -eq "up"}
# Remove any existing IP, gateway from our ipv4 adapter
If (($adapter | Get-NetIPConfiguration -cimSession $Computer.name).IPv4Address.IPAddress) {
 $adapter | Remove-NetIPAddress -cimSession $Computer.name -AddressFamily $IPType -Confirm:$false
}
If (($adapter | Get-NetIPConfiguration -cimSession $Computer.name).Ipv4DefaultGateway) {
 $adapter | Remove-NetRoute -cimSession $Computer.name -AddressFamily $IPType -Confirm:$false
}
 # Configure the IP address and default gateway
$adapter | New-NetIPAddress `
 -AddressFamily $IPType `
 -IPAddress Computer.$IP `
 -PrefixLength $MaskBits `
 -DefaultGateway $Gateway
# Configure the DNS client server IP addresses
$adapter | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses $DNS
}
```

Comment: 'not sure if that's your issue but you forgot a $ sign on the variable for `-IPAddress` for your `New-IPAddress` command.

Comment: Looks like that should be `$Computer.IP` instead of `Computer.$IP`

Comment: Unfortunately it still didnt solve it

Comment: Hmmm ... if I get it right you're trying to remove the IP address from the interface you're connected with. And THEN trying to assign a new IP address ... right? Isn't that like you're sawing off the branch you're sitting on?  ;-)

Comment: Hahaha. You have a point. But i hoped that it would insert all the changes before it would apply them...

Comment: You may try to use a script block you run with `Invoke-Command`. I'm not 100% sure but this should be transfered to the remote computer completely before it gets executed. This way you could circumvent the connection break.